# How to download a file without an extension in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file with no extension on it, but I know it's a tiff.  I want to be able to download this file via PHP.

I created a page with a link to another php page, which has the following content:

```
<?php

$imgPath = 'http://server/23700-b074137f-eb5c-45d6-87c2-13c96812345b';
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=invoice.tiff");
 header("Content-type: image/tiff");
 readfile($imgPath);
?>
```

When I click the link, I get a prompt to download invoice.tiff, but it's 0 bytes.
However, if I rename the file on the server to 23700-b074137f-eb5c-45d6-87c2-13c96812345b.tiff (and change the $imgPath), it works.

How do I accomplish this without renaming the file to include the extension?

Comment: Is there some reason you are proxying the download in this fashion?  It looks like all you are gaining by adding all this extra bandwidth overhead is the ability to rename the file.

Comment: I can't host my page on the server where the file exists.  I need to link to the file so users can download / view it.

Comment: @devlincarate Then just link to the file, don't proxy it through your server.  Like I said.  Other than being able to rename the file, you are gaining nothing from this, but eating up a lot of bandwidth and slowing down the end user's download.

Comment: I originally tried linking to the file based on a network share, but that didn't work since the file doesn't exist on the same server as the web page.  I also ran into a problem with the file not being .tiff, and the user's won't understand what to do with the extension-less file.  How do you suggest I overcome those issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the 'tiff' extension is registered as a known file type on the server, so when you rename and request the tiff it's permissions will allow you to open it. However, with no extension, the security is probably stopping you from reading it, as mentioned by 'Mike B' above. To check this try just entering the file name in your browser address bar and see if it opens, both with and without the 'tiff' extension. There is no workaround for getting past the security issue, short of changing the severs security which would be very bad.

Comment: Yes, this is it!  Looks like a setting in IIS http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/enable-no-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving the file from a URL, therefore activating the 'fopen wrappers' in `readfile`. In general, you should not do this, especially when working locally since it invokes a lot of unnecessary overhead and (in this case) unwanted 'magic' behaviour.

Just use `readfile` on the local path to the file, and it'll be fine, or use `die(file_get_contents($imgPath))` instead of the last line to circumvent PHP's native behaviour.

Comment: it's still downloading with 0 bytes when I try this ?

Comment: also, the file isn't local -- it exists on a different server.

Comment: @devlincarnate There's all kinds of protection schemes to prevent what you're doing.. you'll need a lower level client where you can examine the request/response and find out what you're missing. Maybe they have something in place that reads the user-agent and dies if none exists. File extension has absolutely nothing to do with your problem. Look up common screen-scraping problems and you'll find a solution

Comment: I know the problem must be related to the file extension.  I can see the file on the server.  If I make a copy of the file in the same location but add a .tiff to it, and use the same php (which runs from a different server than where the file is located), I can download the file.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
$imgPath = 'http://server/23700-b074137f-eb5c-45d6-87c2-13c96812345b';
$f = fopen($imgPath, "r");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=invoice.tiff");
header("Content-type: image/tiff");
fpassthru($f);
```

Comment: I'm still getting 0 bytes?  "TIFF file (0 bytes)"

Comment: It is your server? What is in server logs? If it's not your maybe it is blocked for access like this.

Comment: Both servers are on my network.  Would I look in IIS logs?  or ?

Comment: I tested my example on apache (windows). Try find something in IIS logs

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the content-length header like so:

// untested code
header('Content-Length: '.strlen(stream_get_contents($imgPath)));